# Is there way to read the message id of a google pubsub message using apache beam

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

Hi I am trying to pull messages from pubsub using the apache beam

```
PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes().fromSubscription(myTopic)
```

And I am trying to insert the payload to the bigquery. I want to retrieve the message id that a pubsub will generate.

But I am unable to get it, the attributes is also not having the message id.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an issue as of now and currently tracked under this
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3489

We overcame this by generating UUID and stored the message in BQ.